# Whats the logic behind 'impact' argument in ahp topsis function

Tags: r, data-analysis, ahp, mcdm

```
d <- matrix(rpois(12, 5), nrow = 4)
w <- c(1, 1, 2)
i <- c("+", "-", "+")
topsis(d, w, i)
```

this is the function available in R for Ahp topsis, i am confused about how to assign "+" and "-" signs here for "impact" argument. how is it done here in this example

Comment: The [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/topsis/topsis.pdf) states that it's *A character vector of "+" and "-" signs for the way that each criterion influences
on the alternatives.*  Is that not useful?

Comment: i want to know how + sign for is given for 1, and negative for the other 1. it is still not clear, as the ranks changing with the change in impact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question.

'`c("+", "-", "+")`' **indicates which criteria you need to maximise and which criteria you need to minimise.**

So TOPSIS was developed in 1981 by Hwang and Yoon [1] and is a common algorithm used for MCDC (multi-criteria decision making) problems. TOPSIS is based on the premise that the 'best' solution out a set of alternatives, is the one with the closest geometric distance to the ideal solution and the farthest geometric distance to the anti-ideal solution.

Each alternative is characterised with different criteria. Criteria can be beneficial or unbeneficial. If it is beneficial you want to maximise, but if it is a cost you want to minimise.

So, let's say you want to select the 'best' car from an array of car alternatives.

Price is a cost criterion... that you want to minimise. But, maybe 'speed limit' is something you want to maximise.

As said, those '+', '-' indicates which are the attributes are costs and which are benefits so that you can compute the ideal and anti-ideal solution.

Resources:

- TOPSIS Package documentation. Retrieved from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/topsis/topsis.pdf
- Manoj Mathew. TOPSIS - Technique for Order Preference by Similarity to Ideal Solution Retrieved from: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kfcN7MuYVeI

**REFERENCES:**

- 1 Hwang, C. L., & Yoon, K. (1981). Methods for multiple attribute decision making. In Multiple attribute decision making (pp. 58-191). Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I don't have any experience with TOPSIS but the code of that function explains what is going on and matches the description of TOPSIS. You can see the code by typing `topsis`.

matrix `d` in this example is a 4x3 matrix. Each row represents one alternative (for instance , a model of car available in the market) while each column represents a criterion on which these alternatives are to be judged (for instance , you might use cost, efficiency, torque and ground clearance to select a car)

The + and - just show how that particular criteria(column) impacts the outcome. For instance, cost of a car might be a -ve  while torque will be +ve.

The algorithm uses these impact signs to come to a Positive Ideal solution  and a Negative(worst) Ideal solution  .

Positive Ideal solution  is derived by using the max value of +ve columns and the min value of the -ve columns. Here's the relevant line from the code.

`u <- as.integer(impacts == "+") * apply(V, 2, max) + as.integer(impacts == 
        "-") * apply(V, 2, min)`

Negative ideal  is the opposite.

From thereon the code proceeds to find distance of each of our alternatives with these best and worst outcomes and ranks them.

Comment: Now i get the use of impact more clearly. Thank you so much !